# Sharepoint 2013 Rest API: create to multivalue column

Tags: jquery, json, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to save some values to a multi value field, more precisely a survey list column. My attempts:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "somesitecollection/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('survey')/items",
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
   data: JSON.stringify({
       '__metadata': {
           'type': 'SP.Data.SurveyListItem'
       },
       'Question1': {
           "__metadata": {
               "type": "Collection(SP.FieldRatingScaleQuestionAnswer)"
           },
           "results": [2, 3, 5]
       },
       'Comment': "Thanks for..."
   }),
   headers: {
       "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
       "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
   },

   success: function (data) {
       console.log("done");
   },
   error: function (err) {
       console.log(err.status + " - " + err.responseJSON.error.message.value);
   }
});
```

I think there's something wrong with the "results" part in the "Question1" JSON, don't really find the problem though.

Error message:

> "400: An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from
>   the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected."

What does that mean?

### Update

Tried with this code:

```
$.ajax({
url: "somesitecollection/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('survey')/items",
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
   data: JSON.stringify({
       '__metadata': {
           'type': 'SP.Data.SurveyListItem'
       },
       'Question1': {
        "__metadata": {
            "type": "Collection(SP.FieldRatingScaleQuestionAnswer)"
        },
        "results": [
            {
                "Answer": 1
            }, {
                "Answer": 5
            }, {
                "Answer": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    'Comment': "Thanks for..."
}),
headers: {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
},

success: function (data) {
    console.log("ok");
},
error: function (err) {
    console.log(err.status + " - " + err.responseJSON.error.message.value);
}
});
```

No errors now. Only the comment is saved though. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while after posting I found the solution. You have to give the question too:

```
"results": [
   {
      "Answer": 1,
      "Question": "Question 1"
   }, {
      "Answer": 5,
      "Question": "Question 2"
   }, {
      "Answer": 4,
      "Question": "Question 3"
   }
]
```

Comment: I am trying to add on multi value people field and I am getting the same error. any help?

Comment: Try {results: [userId1, userId2]} @sarbashis

Comment: I have tried the same, but no luck. 
I have been searching it for all day long, every where it is given which you have just suggested. But it is not working

Comment: Do you mind creating a new question with all the code (and your request data when you log it)? @sarbashis

Comment: Sure I will do it

Comment: I have created a question, below is the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56010089/how-to-fix-error-in-sharepoint-while-adding-users-in-multi-person-or-group-field