# Error updating person group field using "Send Http Action" in flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to update person/group column using power automate . I am getting below error

**An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected.
clientRequestId: bbf41a14-51dd-4cd0-8ac8-67313f4cf6a5
serviceRequestId: 539c869f-a0d9-b000-66c0-1ac6d790fbd**9

I am able to successfully retrieve the user ID but the update fails.

**{
'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Partner_x0020_Training_x0020_RegistrationListItem' },
'RegisteredByStringId':  '[@{variables('UserID')}]'
}**

When i query using link below, the results for my
"RegisteredBy" column are as below

https://siteurl/Business%20Development/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Partner%20Training%20Registration%20Hub')/items(96)

Business%20Development/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Partner%20Training%20Registration%20Hub')/items(96)

<d:RegisteredById m:null="true" /><d:RegisteredByStringId m:null="true" />

TRied using both these column names but no luck.

Article reference

https://www.about365.nl/2018/08/06/updating-a-multi-people-field-in-sharepoint-with-microsoft-flow/

Comment: This helped !https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56010089/how-to-fix-error-in-sharepoint-while-adding-users-in-multi-person-or-group-field

Comment: {
            "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.MyList2ListItem" },
            "Title": "RestApiCreated",
            "MultiUsersId": { "results": ["12", "23"] }
        }